# Undefined method `add' for Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm implementing this shopping cart gem, but having problems when I add the item to cart in the controller. I tried executing the code using `rails console` and it works fine. Not sure why I'm getting this error from the controller.

#### Error:

[image]

#### products_controller.rb:

```
helper_method :add_to_cart

  def add_to_cart
   @cart = session[:active_cart]
   @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
   @cart.add(@product, 99.99)
  end
```

#### routes.rb

```
post '/add_to_cart/:product_id' => 'products#add_to_cart', :as => 'add_to_cart'
```

#### views/products/index.html

```
        <% products.each do |product| %>
        <%= button_to "Add to Cart", add_to_cart_path(:product_id => product.id), :method => :post %>

          <a href="<%= addresses_path(:brand => product.brand.id, :product_id => product.id) %>" class="list-group-item">
            <%= image_tag product.image.url(:square), class: "product-list-group-item" %>
            <%= product.name %>
            <span class="badge">$<%= number_with_precision(product.price, precision: 2) %></span>
          </a>
        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@cart = session[:active_cart]` this is returning a hash and that's why you get the mentioned error when you call this:

```
@cart.add(@product, 99.99)
```

Because there is no `add` method implemented for hash object.

I suggest you to inspect the `@cart` object in your controller like this:

```
@cart = session[:active_cart]
puts @cart.inspect
puts @cart.class
```

and then you will see, it's a hash object and you should be able to extract the required `cart` object from that hash.

The main issue is to get the correct `@cart` object from the session. Once you do that, then, it should work :)